# Cropping images does not work properly, wrong sections are being stored

Tags: php, javascript, jcrop

So this is the original picture including the rectangle, I want to create a cropped Image from
[image]

And this is what I get after the cropping
[image]

So it can be seen, that the new image has the right dimensions but the wrong part is being cropped.
Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#cropimage').Jcrop(
        {
            aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
            maxSize: [150,200],
            onSelect: updateCoords
        });
    });
    function updateCoords(c)
    {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    };
```

And here is the PHP code

```
function crop($_POST)
{   
    $clipX      = (int)$_POST['x'];
    $clipY      = (int)$_POST['y'];
    $filename   = (string)$_POST['image'];
    $resizedHeight  = (int)$_POST['h'];
    $resizedWidth   = (int)$_POST['w'];

    // Original image's details
    $original   = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images/user_pictures/' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

    $dimensions     = getimagesize($original);
    $old_width  = $dimensions[0];
    $old_height     = $dimensions[1];

    // image = original_image
    $old_image  = call_user_func('imagecreatefrom' . 'jpeg', $original);


    // Crop image
    if (function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor') && ($new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($resizedWidth, $resizedHeight)))
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, $clipX, $clipY, $resizedWidth, $resizedHeight, $old_width, $old_height);

    imagejpeg($new_image,'images/user_pictures/'.$this->getUserID().'_picture.jpg');
}
```

I never used those php functions before but I've read some tutorials and I dont see any errors there.
But there must be at least 1 ... what am I doing wrong ?
The while original Image seems to be resized for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to crop based on (x,y,w,h) (10,15,30,35) then your function would be:

```
imagecopyresampled ( $dst_image , $src_image , 0, 0 , 10 , 15 , 30-10 , 35-15 , 30-10 , 35-15 )
```

since you are copying 20x20 from the original into a new image, those dimensions are your new and dst_w, dst_h as well as your src_w, src_h.

$old_width and $old_height are now the complete width of the original image while they should be the width and height of the cropped part.

```
$old_width = $resizedWidth;
$old_height = $resizedHeight;
```

Comment: This is such a blast .. thank you very much, works like a charm =)